# Navigating between child routes Angular 2

Tags: angular, redirect

I can't seem to be able to navigate between child routes.

Router overview:

```
path: 'parent', component: parentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'child1', component: child1Component },
            { path: 'child2', component: child2Component },
            { path: 'new/:type', component: child3Component },

            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ]
```

i'm in the child1 component trying to navigate to the new/type route like so:

```
this._router.navigate(['new', objType], { relativeTo: this._route });
```

But i keep getting Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'new/asset'.

If i manually insert the url it works fine.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `../`

```
this._router.navigate(['../new', objType], { relativeTo: this._route });
```

Comment: This works, thank you!. The reason i was having so many problems is because i was using the navigate operation in a service and not the component itself.

Comment: I see. The relativeTo route isn't too easy to get inside a service.

Answer (score 7):

```
this.router.navigate(['../../new'], { relativeTo: this._route })
```

Or

```
this.router.navigate(['/parent/new'])
```

Or with anchor tag :

```
 <a [routerLink]=" ['../../new'] ">
      Go to new
 </a>
```

Or  :

```
 <a [routerLink]=" ['/parent/new'] ">
      Go to new
 </a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd start with `/`. Even though it requires `relativeTo` to be treated as a relative path, I'd prefix the path with `/` to make it more obvious.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , it works without the / as well , but to be more clear , I added the slash

Answer (score 3):

When you use `relativeTo` and then try to navigate you should put in the **relative** path, not just the whole one from the parents viewpoint. In your example it should be more like:

```
this._router.navigate([ '../', objType ], { relativeTo: this._route });
```